# AlarmManager setRepeating method is not going off exactly every 60 minutes

Tags: calendar, alarmmanager

my problem is that I have an Alarmmanager that shoudl go off every 60 minutes to a defined time.
This, however, is only working for the first time.
With every next hour passing by Alarmmanager delays its work for 2 or 3 minutes.

Here an example:

hour is set to 4 p. m.
minute is set to 32
timer is set to 60 minutes

```
Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), timer*60000, pi);
```

Maybe someone knows why that is so?

I am using API level 15. As of documentation API 19 setRepeating == setInexactRepeating

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question by referring to the documentation.
API 19 did indeed infer calls to `setRepeating` would be treated as `setInexactRepeating`.

The way to handle this is to set a new alarm when you handle receiving an alarm (>= API 19).
e.g.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setAlarm(AlarmManager alarmManager, long time,
        PendingIntent pIntent, boolean repeat) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
    } else {
        if (repeat) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And then when you receive alarm..

```
/***
 * From version 19 (KitKat) notification that are set repeating aren't
 * exact, so the notification needs to be scheduled again each time it is
 * received
 */
private void scheduleNextNotification() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        return;
    }

    // set alarm that would have otherwise been repeating

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment on this. I found some other strange things regarding AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver, and WAKE_LOCKS. I had a Google Nexus 4 mobile phone where I had implemented an AlarmManager ( SDK < 19 ), a BroadcastReceiver, and a WAKE_LOCK. On the Nexus the AlarmManager never triggered after 30 minutes or so already passed by. But, however, as an example on a Samsung Notes 3 it works without any problems. My mobile phone wakes up, the screen goes on, it does what it should do and goes to sleep again. Maybe, you know something about this problem?